# Menu scroll horizontal - overflow-x overflow-x issue

Tags: scroll, menu, dropdown

i spend some time to make a menu horizontal scrolling. So i tried this:

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow-x: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Problem is that "overflow-y" is now automatic set to "auto" how i found out here, and so dropdowns don´t show.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/crunky/fcjg036s/1/)

I search all stackoverflow and tried everything like parent element with overflow:auto; and so on but nothing works for me fine :(

Is that possible with CSS or is there maybe a better jquery solution?

Thanks!
Best Regards
Marco